# DVI-D Cat5e extender adaptor

Tags: ethernet, dvi, adapter

I have seen these adapters "Mini-DVI graphics extension via Cat 5e/6" online from [here](https://www.reichelt.com/gb/en/?LANGUAGE=EN&CTYPE=0&MWSTFREE=0&CCOUNTRY=447&ARTICLE=136229&PROVID=2788&wt_guka=22596807617_79177387217&PROVID=2788&gclid=CjwKEAjwpdnJBRC4hcTFtc6fwEkSJABwupNiPwSSoJE8kvbeHSaIe1eB_OjE8WifoB21rmdVs2WV8xoCjk3w_wcB).

Looking at the specs of DVI-D it requires 18 conductors minimum. The adaptor uses a single ethernet cable of 4 pairs (8 conductors) total.

I have exhausted searches online to find out how on earth such a device works. Magic? I'm seeking any input or some kind of diagram that shows how this works.

Comment: if you vote down, show some courage, post a comment as to why.

Comment: Not sure, I've used similar extenders for USB connections (webcams in a zoo), and longer runs may or may not work, depending on the actual hardware attached.  Also there is often the option of powering the extender at both ends via wall-wart, doing this seemed to increase the reliability of the connection.  Voting question up 'cause I'm curious now too

Comment: @ivanivan yeh. The spec of adaptor is limited to 20m and states the quality can differ based on the output source. As to be expected. But i just cannot fathom how they make axtra connections with no extra wires. Too much crosstalk to be reusing wires for multiple data .

Comment: You didn't provide your research on how you concluded DVI-D requires 18 wires.  In order to determine how it worked, you would need the physical device, to determine which DVI-D pins are connected to which CAT5 wires.

Comment: They don't make extra connections.  They only transfer the data, the adapter itself handles the reset of the pins.  A small majority of the DVI-D pins are just shield pins.  Only 3 of the pins are for the analog video signal anyways

Answer (score 2):

**It's not purely electrical.** You can't just connect some DVI wires to some UTP wires and expect it to work.

These adapters tunnel DVI-D signals over some other protocol that can be sent over 4 twisted pairs. In other words, the signal is re-encoded into a suitable format, then transmitted and finally decoded back into DVI-D.

Comment: Ah, i understand similar to other devices that do this task. But they have managed to build into a tiny adaptor, and use the 5v on the DVI to power the encode i guess? I am going to ahve to buy a set and pull it apart. Thanks